# django static files (including bootstrap and javascript) problem

Tags: javascript, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, static

The javascript and CSS files are not properly working in dJango. I have tried all the possible ways to i could have. I have attached Index.html and settings.py files code below.

```
// Index.html

{% load static %}
  <title>Careers &mdash; Website Template by Colorlib</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom-bs.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.fancybox.min.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-select.min.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/line-icons/style.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.min.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}">
      <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/isotope.pkgd.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/stickyfill.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fancybox.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/custom.js'%}"></script>
```

```
// Settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
]
```

Comment: Are you add static url to `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`  file?

Comment: Please define "not properly working". What results are you seeing?

Comment: did you set `debug=True` in settings.py?

Comment: @SaeedAlijani This is the code of my urls.py file. have a look
```urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)```

Comment: @suhailvs yes i have set it to True